# while loop update query is not working

Tags: mysql

My update query is like this when i am trying to update records it is update first record only and after that it's give me for all other records

#1062 - Duplicate entry '8-2015-05-16-13-2015-05-23-0.001-0.000-1-R-RI' for key 'processBackupIndex'

```
   for($k=0; $k<count($_REQUEST['designMasterId']); $k++)
    {
      $designMasterId    = isset($_REQUEST['designMasterId'][$k]) && $_REQUEST['designMasterId'][$k] != '' ? $_REQUEST['designMasterId'][$k] : 0;
      $reciveWet         = isset($_REQUEST['reciveWet'][$k]) && $_REQUEST['reciveWet'][$k] != '' ? $_REQUEST['reciveWet'][$k] : 0;
      $rejWet            = isset($_REQUEST['rejWet'][$k]) && $_REQUEST['rejWet'][$k] != '' ? $_REQUEST['rejWet'][$k] : 0;
      $desWet            = isset($_REQUEST['desWet'][$k]) && $_REQUEST['desWet'][$k] != '' ? $_REQUEST['desWet'][$k] : 0;

         $updateProBck = "UPDATE processbackup 
                        SET rDate           = '".$recDate."',
                            reciveWet       = '".$reciveWet."',
                            nextProcessId   = ".$nextProcessId.",
                            processMasterId = ".$processMasterId.",
                            rejWet          = ".$preRej."+".$rejWet.",
                            status = 'R',
                            nxtstatus = 'RI'
                        WHERE designMasterId = ".$designMasterId."
                               AND nextProcessId = ".$nextProcessId."
                               AND desWet = ".$desWet;
                  $updateProBckRes = mysql_query($updateProBck);
                  if(!$updateProBckRes)
                  {
                    echo "Recive Process Backup Insert Fail";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    header("Location:processRecive.php");
                  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a SELECT, but an UPDATE query. It alters the entries. According to the error message (which is quite clear) it alters all records such that they would have an identical unique index entry which apparently is not allowed. Check the tables index definition. Most likely you always use the same parameters for your update statement throughout all loop iterations.

Comment: so if i remove index than it's work or not?

Comment: Well, the rows will probably get updated, but I doubt that is what you want. Because it looks like all rows will get updated to the same values. As written above I assume your real error is how you process your loop. Can't say more since you do not show that code.

Comment: so u want to see whole code @arkascha

Comment: Not the whole code, but probably showing the loop and where the values come from does make sense. Try to reduce the code to the relevant bits.

Comment: me update my code @arkascha

Comment: i cant come on chat @arkascha i dont have enough score

Comment: I cannot spot any reason why the values of `$_REQUEST` should be different between separates iterations of the for loop. Therefore the computations at the top of the loop will always produce the same values, thus all rows get updated to the same values. Which, as said before, most likely is _not_ what you want. So where do _you_ think separate values will come from?

Comment: what you think what is perfect way for it

Comment: Can't tell you, I don't know what your situation is. I asked a clear question. Care to answer it? That might help you to see where the problem is. Or let me ask this way 'round: do you want to update all rows to the same values or not? If not, where do the different values come from?

Comment: right now i am remove index from that table than it's run query @arkascha

Comment: Sure. said so above. Is that what you want? Then all is fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace your

```
header("Location:processRecive.php");
```

to the end of file out of the loop.

Because now if first update is successful you cancel execution and redirect user to some other page.

You code could be:

```
    if(!$updateProBckRes)
    {
        echo "($k) Recive Process Backup Insert Fail";
        exit;
    }

}
header("Location:processRecive.php");
```